# Database table as template in rails using mongod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a organization table which embeds_many organization_memberships with different fields.
I want to capture each organization_memberships data as template from database and after modified by user, I want to save these details in user table as template.

```
{
 "org_name": "xxxxx",
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "4fed411179216d10f000000c"
 },
 "organization_memberships": [
   {
    "family_currently_enrolled": "Yes",
    "_id": {
     "$oid": "4fed411179216d10f0000007"
    },
    "org_id": "KL-NWK-2",
    "age_group_and_school_days": "Two-year-old Tuesday/Thursday",
    "active_member_of_ppc": "Yes"
   },
   {
    "ssssssss": "Yes",
    "_id": {
     "$oid": "4fed411179216d10f000000a"
    },
    "org_id": "KL-NWK-1",
    "eeeeeee": "Two-year-old Tuesday/Thursday",
    "ddddddd": "Yes",
    "ttttt": "Two-year-old Tuesday/Thursday",
    "uuuuuuu": "Yes"
   }
  ],
}
```

Would any one like to suggest me, How can we acheive this?

Comment: Uh can you try to rephrase your question a bit better so it's easier to understand ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, here is my model structure, As you can see. I have organization table which embeds_many organization_membership, And each organization_membership have different fields. I want individual organization_membership field as template, user will modify these template fields. which indeed will store in other table.